# Convert to polar form

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I proceed to convert $$\frac{14\sqrt{3} +30i}{3\sqrt{3}i - 2}$$ to polar form.
I've taken the conjugate twice to get:
$$\frac{(30i+14\sqrt{3})(3\sqrt{3}i+2)(-4-27i)}{745}$$

Can't seem to get further than this, any pointers would be great!

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How on earth did you get $745$ in the denominator? Can you please show the intermediate steps?

Comment: Looking back at my sheet now, I'm not sure how I got the 745 either, think I may have misread when I was expanding or just didn't expand correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: multiply numerator and denominator by the conjugate of $3\sqrt{3}i - 2$. Then you should obtain something like this:
$$z:=\frac{14\sqrt{3} +30i}{3\sqrt{3}i - 2}=\frac{(14\sqrt{3} +30i)(-3\sqrt{3}i - 2)}{(3\sqrt{3})^2+4}\\=\frac{62(-3i+\sqrt{3})}{31}=2(-3i+\sqrt{3})=4\sqrt{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)=4\sqrt{3}e^{-i\pi/3}.$$
So $|z|=4\sqrt{3}$ and $\mbox{arg}(z)=-\pi/3$ (or $2\pi-\pi/3=5\pi/3$).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Why don't we convert the numerator to polar form $r_1\exp (i \theta_1)$

and the denominator to polar from $r_2 \exp(i \theta_2)$.

then the magnitude would be $\frac{r_1}{r_2}$ and the corresponding angle is $\theta_1-\theta_2$